# How to write a bash script that downloads files from the internet?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, wget

I’m quite new to programming and I’m trying to create a script where the user will connect to 8.8.8.8. If the connection is successful, then the script will prompt the user which website they want to download. The process is repeated until the user types “exit” (the use of a while loop)
So far that is the code I have written. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

ping -c 4 8.8.8.8
while true;
do
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
read -p "please type a website URL to download or type exit to quit" URL
wget -m $URL
else
echo "No internet connection"
exit 1
done
```

Comment: **1** You don’t check the result of `ping`, but always continue. **2** There’s nothing whatsoever that checks for the word `exit`.

Comment: So check if user typed exit.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

ping -c 4 8.8.8.8
if [ $? -gt 0 ]
then
    exit 1
fi
while true
do
    read -p "please type a website URL to download or type exit to quit: " URL
    if [[ $URL == "exit" ]]
    then
        exit 1
    fi
    wget -m $URL
done
```

step 1: get return code from ping and exit if this is not successful

step 2: read the url and exit if user types in "exit", otherwise `wget`

Comment: Thanks..now i understand

Comment: You don't need a colon after a command if it is last in line. `while true; do⏎` on same line, or `while true⏎` `do⏎`.

Comment: You're right, I just copy/paste the script from the question. Fixed the answer.